# Install Python3.7 on Ubuntu Machine, dist-packages empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, pip

I've installed Python3.7 on Ubuntu using `sudo apt-get install python3.7`. Python3.7 installs, but the dist-packages folder is empty and pip and other packages cannot be installed.

Is there a way to build out the dist-packages folder?

Answer (score 1):

You should install pip3 through apt too!

```sh
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: I did try that, and I get this error:
"The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pip : Depends: python3-setuptools but it is not installable
               Depends: python3-requests but it is not installable
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not installable"

Comment: Perhaps first update apt `sudo apt update` and then try to get all the packages needed for building `sudo apt install python3-dev python3-setuptools build-essential`

Comment: Plausibly there's some weirdness with you having installed 3.7 where the latest version is 3.8 (at least in Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and start again following the guide given by python or see if there's anything you've missed.
https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/linux/

Also I'm not sure if this will work, but try `sudo apt-get install python`.